# Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS - ombok-ast-0.2.3.jar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I tried data binding and I need change build:gradle like this:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

now I cant run my project

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS
  >   File1: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
  >   File2: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar

my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':**')
    compile project(':**')
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    //    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'

    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `compile project(':**')` is a redaction of two separate projects, and not a duplication?

Comment: They are diffirent, i just censored them

Answer (score 1):

Like the error states you're trying to package the *AUTHORS* file from different jars; so you should just exclude it from being packaged.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'AUTHORS' // will not include AUTHORS file
}
```

You should merge your other packagingOptions files like this

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'AUTHORS' // will not include AUTHORS file
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
    // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
    // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```